# How to find a subfield in Mongo without knowing the parent field?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Given the following collection:

```
db.test.insertMany([
    {"_id": 1, "Jimmy": {"Loved by mom": true}},
    {"_id": 2, "Andrew": {"Loved by mom": false}},
    {"_id": 3, "Nicholas": {"Loved by mom": true}}",
    {"_id": 4, "Sarah": {"Loved by dad": true}}
]);
```

Is there a way to search for all documents that have the subfield `"Loved by mom"`, without knowing what the parent field is called? To (hopefully) simplify this task, the desired subfield is always located at depth 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to search for all documents that have the subfield
>   "Loved by mom", without knowing what the parent field is called?

This Aggregation query can do that:

```
var loved_by_mom = "Loved by mom";

db.loved.aggregate( [
        { $addFields: { fieldNameValues: { $objectToArray: "$$ROOT" } } },
        { $unwind: "$fieldNameValues" },
        { $addFields: { fldType: { $type: "$fieldNameValues.v" } } },
        { $match: { fldType: "object" } },
        { $addFields: { objs: { $objectToArray: "$fieldNameValues.v" } } },
        { $unwind: "$objs" },
        { $match: { "objs.k": loved_by_mom } }, 
        { $project: { fieldNameValues: 0, fldType: 0, objs: 0 } }
] )
```

Answer (score 0):

string `$search` from `$text`, This query returns the documents that contain the term `Loved by mom` in the indexed subject field, or more precisely, the stemmed version of the word:

```
db.test.find( { $text: { $search: "Loved by mom" } } )
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know an easy way to do what you want.

In your case I would change the way your documents are inserted into MongoDB:

```
db.test.insertMany ([
     {"_id": 1, "name": "Jimmy", "lovedBy": {"mom": true}},
     {"_id": 2, "name": "Andrew", "lovedBy": {"mom": false}},
     {"_id": 3, "name": "Nicholas", "lovedBy": {"mom": true}},
     {"_id": 4, "name": "Sarah", "lovedBy": {"dad": true}}
]);
```

Then you could make the query like this:

```
db.test.find({"lovedBy.mom" : {$exists: true}});
```

It is important to always have a document structure that allows you to query information in a simpler way.

Although MongoDB allows you to have a flexible structure, I would not recommend using documents that have unique fields for each document.

It would not make sense for each document to have a unique field and you want to search for the child fields of those unique fields.

This way you would only be hindering your work.